# How to open userform if a cell in the columns F; H; I is clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

I was able to create a Datepicker following a tutorial.

I want the userform to open automatically if a cell in the columns F; H; I is clicked.

In the tutorial I created a little icon to open the userform. This doesn’t seem natural to me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write an event procedure. Something like this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("F:G,I:I")) Is Nothing) Then
        YourUserForm.Show
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: In case you're not aware, that sub will need to be pasted into the ***Sheet*** object, not a new module.